# QgsRubberBand constructor deprecation warning

Tags: pyqgis, qgsrubberband

I construct a `QgsRubberBand` in PyQGIS 2.18.17 the following way

```
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
my_rubber = QgsRubberBand(canvas, QGis.WKBPolygon)
```

according to https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsRubberBand.html

and get a `Deprecation Warning` like

```
2018-03-23T11:56:19 1   warning:C:/Users/Jochen/.qgis2/python/plugins\BBBBPlanung\bbbb_planung_dockwidget.py:666: DeprecationWarning: QgsRubberBand constructor is deprecated
          my_rubber = QgsRubberBand(canvas, QGis.WKBPolygon)
```

Why this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should have had a deeper look into `QGis.GeometryType` https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQGis.html#a09947eb19394302eeeed44d3e81dd74b

According to this

```
my_rubber = QgsRubberBand(canvas, QGis.Polygon)
```

is the correct way, and the `Deprecation Warning` has vanished.